# Why Ubuntu do not Delete from OS and BIOS?

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, lubuntu, 21.10

I have a BIOS InsydeH20 Rev5.0 on a Lenovo Ideapad 330S 14-IKB. So, I installed Ubuntu version 21.10 (on SDD) an already uninstalled (version 21.10) from Bios, Disk Management, CMD (bcdedit) and EasyUEFI (Program); However, it still show up in Bios and Boot Menu; So I want to remove it COMPLETELY, because otherwise I would not let myself install 22.04 LTS version.

Comment: If you install Lubuntu is BIOS/legacy.CSM mode the uEFI tables are not touched and no entries are created/modified; instead the MBR itself is used. You won't see the MBR entry in uEFI applications as its a reserved location on the disk (*every disk in fact*) reserved for that purpose. You just replace it with something else as there is no delete process (*that makes no sense as the definition/rules were created before dual boots existed so it's replaced and not deleted*), but uEFI tools will ignore it as it's only used in legacy/BIOS boots.

Comment: FYI:  The BIOS/legacy boot/MBR will not impact uEFI/Secure-uEFI installation anyway;  as the uEFI setup ignores it by design to be backwards compatible.  Ubuntu installs are also QA-tested to confirm this for desktop releases anyway which include Lubuntu's `calamares` or Ubuntu's `ubiquity` installer (which work different in regards uEFI/MBR somwhat though how the ISO is written to thumb-drive can impact what occurs and you didn't provide those details).

Comment: If you run this report we can see the details of your installs. Your system is UEFI, although many vendors still call it BIOS. Microsoft has required vendors to install in UEFI boot mode with gpt partitioning since 2012. Remove UEFI entries: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1195682/boot-problem-in-uefi-multiboot-system-with-separate-drives-in-ubuntu-18-04/1195984#1195984