# Partition not showing while installing dual boot Ubuntu Mate

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10, ubuntu-mate

I have brought a new desktop which has pre-installed windows 10. I want to install Ubuntu along with windows(dual boot). I have inserted an additional hard disk and unallocated 100GB for Ubuntu.

Please check this image [image: .]

Now when I try to install Ubuntu it is not detecting partition storage. Please check the attached screenshot. Please instruct me to install dual boot Ubuntu.

Instlaiton screen
[image: .]
Error
[image: .]

Comment: What brand/model system? Is UEFI & SSD firmware updated (even if new). Added AHCI driver to Windows & changed UEFI to AHCI for drives? Turned off Windows fast start up? Made new drive as gpt not old MBR?  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1130372/dual-booting-win-10-and-ubuntu-18-04-on-two-separate-physical-ssds &  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1167910/unable-to-properly-boot-linux-from-external-ssd/1167940#1167940 &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/913716/dual-boot-on-seperate-drives-best-configuration

Comment: @oldfred Dell Desktop. Changed SATA operation from RAIDto AHCI. The system has 512GB SSD. I have inserted an additional 1 TB. Now I have unallocated 100 GB from 1 TB HDD. But While installing it is not showing this 100 GB Partition, instead, it shows the whole 1TB HDD(Along with SSD). Can you help me?

Comment: Is Windows fast start up on? That sets hibernation flag and then NTFS partitions may not be seen. Or did you convert from basic to dynamic partitions? Dynamic partitions with Windows do not work in Linux. post this in question: `sudo fdisk -lu`