# How "safe" is to install Linux to a second drive?

Tags: dual-boot, windows

I have a healthy and working machine that has Windows 10 on it. The PC has two SSDs.
Windows is installed in one of them. There is nothing in the second drive.

If I use a Xubuntu 20.04 installer I have in a usb stick to install this OS on this second drive, will this break the Windows install?

I noticed during the installer ( which I still did not run completely )  that the same does not even detect windows is in the second drive.

Should I go ahead and install it though? I do not want to break it and be forced to reinstall windows all over again, but there is no problem if I have both.

Comment: Before installing disable Fast Startup in Windows and make sure you're booting the USB installation media in the same mode as Windows, UEFI or BIOS. Otherwise the os-prober won't detect Windows.

Comment: You need to partition in advance using gpt & include an ESP. Some examples: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1130372/dual-booting-win-10-and-ubuntu-18-04-on-two-separate-physical-ssds & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1167910/unable-to-properly-boot-linux-from-external-ssd/1167940#1167940 &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/913716/dual-boot-on-seperate-drives-best-configuration