# New Ubuntu installed on new drive, boot loader is in old drive

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2

### This is a follow-up for [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/1352830/578067) question

I installed a new Ubuntu installation on a new SSD.
In the installation, I selected the new SSD as the device for boot loader installation.

When I turn on my PC I see a GRUB bootloader screen with all 3 of my OSs (new Ubuntu, Windows and old Ubuntu) and everything works fine.

However, when I enter BIOS I see that this boot-loader is actually the one that belongs to the old Ubuntu. This boot loader is in the old SSD that is actually used for Windows, while the old Ubuntu is in a partition on a HDD.

My questions:

1. Is it safe to remove the partition (on the HDD) of the previous Ubuntu installation?
2. Why did the boot loader install on the old SSD when I explicitly selected the new one?

Comment: You cannot just specify with UEFI, that only works with BIOS. With UEFI, it defaults to first ESP it sees. Second drive 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1296065/dual-booting-w10-ubuntu-with-2-separate-ssds-in-uefi-mode/1296153#1296153 & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator/1056079#1056079
 Do you have an ESP on each drive? As posted before best to have one on every drive.  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379

Comment: I have an EFI in my old SSD and an EFI in my HDD. I wanted to have an EFI partition on the new SSD which is why I choose to install the bootloader on that drive, but it didn't give me any warning that it's not doing that.

Comment: UEFI/gpt partitioning in Advance, new versions use swap file so swap partition optional:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation